# How to publish nuget package update?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

Well, this is my first Nuget package I publish, it's as simple as any first..

I've published it through this command line:

```
nuget push PKG.1.0.0.0.nupkg 0000000-000-0000-0000-0000000000 -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package
```

but I don't know how to update it, you know how difficult it is to google "update nuget package"!

Answer (score 4):

Changing the version number is all what I needed,
but changing the package name will likely publish new package

Comment: Do you know how to perform these changes in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you do not want to use the CLI and push your package, is to go to [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) and in the upload section, upload your package with a higher version number. It will pick up the package ID so you wont be publishing a whole new package. That will update your package on your behalf after [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) validates the uploaded package.